# Zend Framework 1.12 Login Session Length per User

Tags: zend-framework

I have set my session options in ZendFramework as defined in http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html to default to one week in my Bootstrap file as such:

```
[zendsession]
name = name
save_path = "../zend_sessions"
use_only_cookies = on
remember_me_seconds = 604800

$cacheConfig = new Zend_Config_Ini(ROOT_DIR.'/application/configs/application.ini', 'zendsession');
Zend_Session::setOptions($cacheConfig->toArray());
```

And is it working.

I would like to know if I can overwrite the duration when logging in individual users, which currently happens like this:

```
$storage = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
$storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject());
```

With regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Zend_Session::rememberMe()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html#zend.session.global_session_management.rememberme) anywhere in your code, as long its done before the user's session is initialised.